# Icecast2 - No SSL capability

Tags: lets-encrypt, icecast, internet-radio

I am trying to add SSL to my Icecast2 but I always get the following error:
*connection/get_ssl_certificate No SSL capability*

This is the installed version:

```
icecast2:
Installed: 2.4.4-1
Candidate: 2.4.4-1
Version table:
 2.4.4-3~bpo10+1 100
    100 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main amd64 Packages
*** 2.4.4-1 500
    500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 2.4.4-1 500
    500 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/multimedia:/xiph/Debian_10 ./ Packages
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that Debian alway took the official repo instead of the XIPH repo (which supports SSL) - It was solved by changing the position of the XIPH repo over the official repo in the sources.list!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, and now I'm streaming with HTTPS:

**First:** You need to know if your Icecast was compiled with SSL:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/icecast | grep -i ssl
```

You have Icecast with SSL if it returns something like this:

```
libssl.so.1.1 => /lib64/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f9f693ad000)
```

If not, uninstall icecast and install first of all these dependencies, then install icecast again:

> ```
> libxml2
> libxml2-devel
> libxslt
> libxslt-devel
> curl Version >= 7.10
> libcurl
> libcurl-devel
> libogg/libvorbis Version >= 1.0
> libvorbis-devel
> libogg-devel
> OpenSSL
> libtheora
> libtheora-devel
> speex
> speex-devel
> mod_ssl
> ```

**Second:** (only for testing purposes, the right way is to have a cert from a Certificate Authority) Generate a self-signed certificate with openSSL:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /etc/ssl/private
$ cd /etc/ssl/private
$ sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout localdomain.key -out localdomain.crt
```

**Third:** Put your certificate and private key in a single file, as Icecast requires everything in one file:

```
$ sudo cat localdomain.crt localdomain.key > localdomain_pairkeys.pem
```

**Fourth:** Change the owner of this file to icecast (confirm the icecast user in your /etc/passwd):

```
$ sudo chown icecast:icecast localdomain_pairkeys.pem
```

**Fifth:** Paste these lines in your /etc/icecast.xml

```
<listen-socket>
    <port>443</port>
    <ssl>1</ssl>
    <bind-address>YOUR IP ADDRESS</bind-address>
</listen-socket>
```

Inside "paths" closure:

```
<ssl-certificate>/etc/ssl/private/localdomain_pairkeys.pem</ssl-certificate>
    <ssl-allowed-ciphers>ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS</ssl-allowed-ciphers>
```

**Finally:** Start the service (this is how I start it in Fedora, so it can listen in port 443, don't know why but with *"systemctl start icecast"* it listens only in port 8000):

```
$ sudo icecast -c /etc/icecast.xml
```

That's it, I hope it is useful!

These pages have helped me too:
https://www.icecast.org/docs/icecast-trunk/config_file/
[Why Icecast2 does not want to give the stream through https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237748/why-icecast2-does-not-want-to-give-the-stream-through-https)
[Icecast 2 and SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49300064/icecast-2-and-ssl)