# Icecast2 doesn't recognize SSL certificate

Tags: icecast

I have an Icecast2 streaming server that I am trying to install a Lets encrypt SSL certificate on I have purchased the certificate and I have followed the problems and instructions from the two stack overflow problems that this topic is previously mentioned on.

Links to the two discussions
[Why Icecast2 does not want to give the stream through https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237748/why-icecast2-does-not-want-to-give-the-stream-through-https)
[Icecast 2 and SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49300064/icecast-2-and-ssl)

I have the following code from my Icecast.xml

```
<icecast>
    <limits>
        <sources>5</sources>
    </limits>
    <authentication>
        <source-password>........</source-password>
        <relay-password>........</relay-password>
        <admin-user>admin</admin-user>
        <admin-password>........</admin-password>
    </authentication>

    <hostname>localhost</hostname>
    <listen-socket>
        <port>80</port>
<shoutcast-mount>/live.mp3</shoutcast-mount>
        <ssl>1</ssl>
    </listen-socket>
 
    <hostname>stream.,,,,.com</hostname>
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8443</port>
<shoutcast-mount>/live.mp3</shoutcast-mount>
        <ssl>1</ssl>
    </listen-socket>

    <fileserve>1</fileserve>
    <paths>
        <logdir>./logs</logdir>
        <webroot>./web</webroot>
        <adminroot>./admin</adminroot>
        <alias source="/" dest="/status.xsl"/>
        <ssl-certificate>/usr/share/icecast2/icecast.pem</ssl-certificate>
    </paths>
    <logging>
        <accesslog>access.log</accesslog>
        <errorlog>error.log</errorlog>
      <loglevel>3</loglevel> <!-- 4 Debug, 3 Info, 2 Warn, 1 Error -->
    </logging>
</icecast>
```

My security certificate is in the file icecast.pem and contains the certificate first then the private key second as a work around based off of the second discussion link I pasted here.

After doing the following above nothing has changed and the link to the streaming server still tells me that it is not secure still even after doing the code work above.

Any assistance you guys are able to provide is appreciated Thanks!

After doing the following above nothing has changed and the link to the streaming server still tells me that it is not secure still even after doing the code work above even though it is supposed to be secure now.

Any assistance you guys are able to provide is appreciated Thanks!

Comment: Which version of icecast is this? How are you starting it?

Comment: Icecast2 Version 2.x. I am starting it with the butt-0.1.12 software. Let me know if you need anything else Thank you.

Comment: there have been many Icecast releases in the 2.x series and there is a quite divergent fork called "-kh", so please be specific. Unless you have very good reasons I'd recommend just installing the Icecast 2 package for your Linux distribution.

Comment: To be honest with you I inherited this system with no background on it so I am not sure what version it actually is the info I gave you above is the info that the program said they were but what I can tell you is that they are the older version from 2008. Still works perfectly fine just need a security certificate now. Where would you go to get the installation for Icecast 2 package?